# use jar file from s3 bucket in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to create a beanstalk app. It offers to upload a file or choose a s3 bucket.

I have uploaded some jar files to a s3 bucket and want to pick the bucket instead of uploading them.

The reason I do this is that in the next step I want to do it with terraform and I don't find any configuration in terraform to upload a file directly.

My problem now is that beanstalk keeps reporting an error.

> Source code is required.Source code URL must be a valid S3 location.

[image: beanstalk menu showing s3 url and error]

How can I make this work? Or is there another way I can do it later with terraform. I don't understand how to get the actual code there with the AWS provider. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this using [aws_elastic_beanstalk_application_version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_application_version). Prior to creating that resource you have to upload your jar to s3 using [aws_s3_bucket_object](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/s3_bucket_object).

Comment: ok, I see thanks. Why is this not working from the aws console? I have a bucket if jar files. The url is surely correct. When I hit it, I can download the jar.

Comment: @TheFool Try with different format of the url where bucket-name is first: `https://<bucket-name>.s3..../front-end.jar`

Comment: yes, different format worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please use **Object URL** instead of **S3 URI** in *Public S3 URL* field while creating Beanstalk environment.

Please refer below example Snippet:

[image]